# MySQLi Specific Querys dont work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried to get the total rows from specific table:

```
 $result = mysqli_query( $dbcnx, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `servers` ;" );
 $total = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );
 return $total[ 0 ] == 0 ? 0 : $total[ 0 ];
```

I just changed from MySQL to MySQLi.
The value should be 1 as the number of rows, but it returns empty string if I don't check it.

I tried to check if there are any erros but it shows nothing.

What is the problem with my code?

**Edited:**

i enabled error report and it shows now

> Undefined index $dbcnx

But the connection is success, So what should i do?

This is the connection script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
ini_set('xmlrpc_errors', true);


$dbcnx = mysqli_connect( $hostname, $user, $pass, $database );

if( mysqli_connect_errno() )
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Please add debug info by providing the output of `echo mysqli_error()` placed after the query command. Please also make sure to [enable error reporting](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/).

Comment: Could you try the query without the semicolon: `FROM \`servers\` ");`, mysqli typically handles multiple queries very differently to the older mysql library, it's possible the semicolon is causing it's behaviour to change.

Comment: See my edit, the $dbcnx causing all this, but only for this specific query

Comment: Mmm, the connection script and the first script are different?

Comment: `$dbcnx = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); ` run this and check whats the error

Comment: check this link `http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php` and be sure you connect properly

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, I fixed the problem 2 days ago.

The problem was with the use of it.

i use the connection $dbcnx in function so i added global $dbcnx and it worked.

Thank you all!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to have count(*) in your query string as mysqli has an integrated function for counting the number of rows.

```
<?php
//CONN STRING
$dbConn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $pass, $database);

//CHECK CONN
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//QUERY TO RUN
$query = "SELECT id FROM servers ORDER BY id";

if ($result = mysqli_query($dbConn, $query)) {

    // GET # of ROWS
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    //OUTPUT %d will take whats in $count
    printf("Result set has %d rows.", $count);

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

//CLOSE CONN
mysqli_close($dbConn);
?>
```

Comment: As @scragar says in the other answer, never do this. You are obtaining all the data from the table only to count results

Comment: Where is your $_POST for all the connection string variables? Your connection string will return undefined index is your username and password are not valid